# Numpy creation of new array using 2 existing arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Good Day Sir/Maám,

I am very new to the world of python, numpy, pandas and matplotlib.  Although I am learning lot I am now stuck.  I normally use Excel and can do this problem in VBA and MS Query without issue, but it is slow.  I have looked thought the Numpy documentation, searched the web and this resource but I could not find anything that relates to this issue.

The problem I have is a list of vehicle registrations in one array and a list of dates in another array which changes for each task I conduct.  I want to create a new array that is a combination of vehicle registrations and dates to be used in further analysis.

Example:
The arrays for 100 vehicle registrations and 4000 dates would be as follows:

```
Veh_reg = np.arange([‘0001’,’0100’) 

date_array = np.arange(‘2010-01-01’,…. ‘2018-01-02’,…., dtype = np.datetime64)
```

I need a new array/dataframe created that lists every separate vehicle registration with every date against it.  Such as:

```
Reg     Date

0001    2010-01-01

0001    2018-01-02……

0001    last date in date_array.
```

Iterate though both arrays……

```
0100    2010-01-01

0100    2018-01-02….

0100    last date in date_array.
```

I have tried using for and while loops with no luck at all.  I am sure that this is an easy solution I am just not getting.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far!

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. What is the input? Numpy arrays of strings? There is nothing like `np.arange([‘0001’,’0100’])`, this only works with integers or float. And what would be your desired output? A list of pairs? A pandas dataframe? A numpy array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your problem, it seems you just want all the combinations of the elements two arrays, is that correct?
If so, you could do:

```
import numpy as np
cars = [1, 2]
dates = [3, 4]
result = np.stack(np.meshgrid(cars, dates), -1).reshape(-1, 2)
```

or in plain Python (no numpy):

```
result = []
for c in cars:
    for d in dates:
        result.append([c,d])
```

I here provide examples with basic types, since you didn't provide working code in your question.

Comment: Hello Maciek,
Many thanks for the reply.Tthe python method method worked perfectly.
I tried using the numpy method using my data, for vehicle registrations and dates and all I got was returned was the error code:
"TypeError: ufunc multiply cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[D]') and dtype('int32')".   Do you have any idea why this occurs?

Comment: I see that the numpy stack method complains when the date type is used. If I were you, I would just stick to the plain Python solution, in fact using numpy here might be just an overkill. I hope that's fine!

Comment: I agree, keep it simple.  Many thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
Veh_reg = np.array(['0001','0100'])
date_array = np.array(['date1', 'date2'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'Veh_reg':Veh_reg, 'date_array':date_array})
```